# If ComboBox value then radiobutton visible JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, combobox

Hello so i need help for HTML and JavaScript code ...
In HTML i have RadioButtons and Drop down list (combo box).
But i need JavaScript code . If i choose Value from combobox "volvo" then show 3 radio buttons.
I'm working on some test/quizz
I need this help fast.Please help...

```
<select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="inputC[0]" value="0" /> 0</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="inputC[0]" value="1" /> 1</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="inputC[0]" value="2" /> 2</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: What have you already tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

So, here is your HTML (a little optimized markup):

```
<select id="car" onchange="checkTest()">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi" >Audi</option>
</select>
<label for="inputC[0]0">
    <input type="radio" name="inputC[0]" id="inputC[0]0" value="0" />
    0
</label>
<label for="inputC[0]1">
    <input type="radio" name="inputC[0]" id="inputC[0]1" value="1" />
    1
</label>
<label for="inputC[0]2">
    <input type="radio" name="inputC[0]" id="inputC[0]2" value="2" />
    2
</label>
```

And here is your JS (this is just for explanation porpuses):

```
var inputC = document.getElementsByName('inputC[0]'); // Get all Radiobuttons
for(var i = 0; i < inputC.length; i++) { //Loop through every Radiobutton
    if(document.getElementById('car').selectedIndex == 0) { //Check if Combobox Index 1 is Selected
            inputC.item(i).parentNode.style.visibility = 'hidden'; //Set Parent of Radiobutton (label) to hidden
    } else {
            inputC.item(i).parentNode.style.visibility = 'visible'; //Set Parent of Radiobutton (label) to visible
    }
}
```

Hope i could help!

Comment: Nothing...
I need some code that will in start say to radiobuttons to be incisible.Then through JavaScript to be visible...

Comment: Then simply add a `style="visibility: hidden;"` in all `<label>` tags